# Angular2: use custom times in component view with ngIf

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm trying to show/hide a div on my page where the condition is base on the usage of a const enum:

```
export const enum TipoMensagem {
    Sucesso,
    Erro
}
```

And this is what I'd like to write on my view:

```
<div [class]="msgInformacao.msgKind === MsgKind.Error ? 'text-danger' : ' text-info'"><strong>{{msgInformacao.info}}</strong></div>
```

This results in a runtime error saying that it's not possible to access property Error of undefined.

If I wrap the condition on a controller method, everything workds out great:

```
<div [class]="hasError() ? 'text-danger' : ' text-info'"><strong>{{msgInformacao.msg}}</strong></div>
```

And then, there's an error method on the controller that looks like this:

```
hasError(): boolean {
    return this.msgInformacao.msgKind === MsgKind.Error;
}
```

What I'd like to know is if option A (using the enum on the view) is supported and if it is, what do I need to do to use it?

Thanks

Luis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use option A if you set a variable in the component with MsgKind so it can be accessed on the template.

Something like this might work:

```
import { MsgKind } from './MsgKind'

class Component {
    MsgKind = MsgKind;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not supported.

You can only access members and methods of the component or directive the template belongs to. So everything you can access with `this.XXX` is also accessible in the template, hence `hasError()` works and trying to use anything outside your class scope (eg a const enum) does not.